# After Windows 7 SP1 IIS errors with "Invalid application path"

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-7

I'm getting this new, strange error message in IIS after updating Windows 7 (x64) with SP1.

1. Open the IIS Manager
2. Browse to an exisiting Virtual Application (or create a new one)
3. Open its **Basic Settings** dialog
4. Click **Test Settings**
5. The error message comes up

It's happening with new Applications and also with ones that were already there (and without that problem) before.

The applications themselves continue to work.

Has anybody figured this one out yet?

Comment: What path is your website root set to?
* Does the path exist?
* Does your IIS user have access to the path?
* Try adding a simple .gif to the path. Can you access it?
* If successful, try an ASP.NET page. Does it work?

Comment: @Erik, there are no problems opening the site in the browser, seeing the pages of images. The problem I'm asking about is in the IIS Manager.

Comment: But, what does the error message say? Are you sure you're not using Integrated Security, and the IIS Manager is unable to test this, as you're not authenticated when running through IIS Manager?

Answer (score 4):

Doublecheck that your specific version of ASP.NET is allowed in IIS as follows:

1. Select the top (root) server in IIS Manager.
2. Doubleclick ISAPI and CGI Restrictions.
3. If your version of ASP.NET is Not Allowed, right click and Allow it.

This solved it for me, hope it works for you too.

Comment: Thank you.  Many questions come out of this.  I wonder why they make this the default.  Why isn't this the first answer when looking up this error? the list goes on.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, solved by giving explicit permissions to IIS_IUSRS in the folder where my application is.

Comment: What explicit permission did you give. I tried giving it Full Control and it didn't help. Just to be clear, I had all the right permissions before Win7-SP1. Clicking Test Settings back then used to work just fine.

Comment: Just Read, nothing fancy...

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem, here is my solution.

1. Check the application pool your application is using.
2. Click on application pool and click on Advanced settings, will lead to new window.
3. Check the .NET Framework version
4. Set Load User Profile to True
5. Set ping enabled to True

Answer (score 1):

Something that worked for me was to Allow 32bit applications on the applicationpool.

It seem that the application I ran was a 32bit one

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Within IIS in the "Advanced settings" of the Application Pool(s), under "General" there is an "Enable 32-Bit Applications" setting. When I set that to True, this error went away for me.

Comment: I had tried that already. Tried again. Made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I still haven’t find a solution, but find a workaround.

You can manually change IIS configuration, in system32\intsrv\config\applicationHost.config. Just manually create (copy-paste) section in  and .

Comment: Your answer seems to be missing information.  Might want to fix that, or remove it, if you don't want to be down-voted.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO ... This test is of little value unless you want to test a specific user and even then it's marginal ... to add user accounts to folders to allow this test to work (as others stated) marginalizes your security... better to not have this test then to add users to folders and jeopardize your security in any way, shape or form...

As long as your site works... that should be your benchmark...

Answer (score 0):

This is really seems like a **bug** in the IIS user interface:  When "Application user (pass through authentication)" is selected the web site is expecting a browser to send user credentials from the currently logged on user.  The site will then load because "anonymous" authentication is enabled for the site. However when testing through the IIS MMC, "Test Settings..." button no credentials are being presented to be used for directory access hence you see that "Invalid application path" error message in the IIS MMC.  If you click "Browse.... then the default browser on the web server, usually Internet Explorer, will present your credentials.  In most circumstances you can ignore this bug your web site works.